# I updated MiKteX some days ago (11/08); Since I dit that, "lstlisting" doesn't work

Tags: listings, code, r

I want to include R code in a tex source by using the environment `lstlisting` from the package `listings`.
It is a paper I began to work on some weeks ago.
The inclusion was working correctly during some times. But recently I updated MiKteX and after that things don't work anymore. Everything is going as if  `\usepackage{listings}` in the preamble had no effect...  when MiKteX meets lines after `\begin{listlisting}` it says  "Undefined control sequence"

In fact I am using `\begin{lstlisting}` not `\begin{listlisting}` as written wrongly in the text above.

Below the code and the error message:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}  

\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=R]
par(mfrow= c(2,1))
phi<-  0.85; phi2<-  -0.85 
set.seed(1001)    
y1<- arima.sim(n=200,list(ar=phi1),sd=1.0)     
plot(y1,type="line", main=bquote(Y[t]==.(phi1)*Y[t-1]+epsilon[t]))
set.seed(1001)
y2<- arima.sim(n=200,list(ar=phi2),sd=1.0)    
plot(y2,type="line", main=bquote(Y[t]==.(phi2)*Y[t-1]+epsilon[t]))
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

error message:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \textminus 
                      
l.18 phi<-
            0.85; phi2<-  -0.85
?
```

Comment: Are you using `\begin{lstlisting}`, or `\begin{listlisting}`?  The latter doesn't exist.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The MWE as listed works just fine.

Comment: `\textminus`?  I don't suppose you copied a `-` into your document, and pasted something that looks like a `-` but is actually a slightly different character?  Could you delete all hyphens and retype them?

Comment: When I drop the "<-" and use "=" I get a similar message:! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \textminus 
                      
l.16 phi=  0.85; phi2=  -0.85

Comment: I tried to do what Teepeemm proposes. I deleted all the hypens and retype them. But the result is the same. To overcome the problem I will try to use Sweave...

Comment: @Gmistral When I copy and paste what you have posted, it compiles without error.  What happens if you remove line 16: `phi<-  0.85; phi2<-  -0.85`.

Comment: Answer to Teepeem. If I remove line 16 I get the same error message for the next "minus" sign that is "y1<- arima.sim(n=200,list(ar=phi1),sd=1.0)" and so on. The only way not to have any error message is to delete all the "minus" signs of the text...!!!

Comment: What if you add `\providecommand{\textminus}{-}` to your preamble?  That wouldn't fix the root of the problem, but could conceivably get you the output you want.

Comment: Answer to Teepeem. Yes it works.  But it seems quite strange and worrying. A suggestion than just quite sharp "geeks" can propose. But thanks a lot for your help. I have an other problem which concerns the color...I will create a new question on the site...

Comment: The next step for this problem would be to comment out the other packages (color, graphicx, ams*, babel, inputenc) and the options to get this a bit more minimal.  Then, add the command `\listfiles` before your document class to show the versions of everything at the end of the log.